# What are the options to port game to mobile from Adobe Animate?

Tags: flash, 2d-games

Is it possible to use Flash in mobile games?  I've found the [GAF Converter](https://gafmedia.com/) does a pretty decent job with porting them to mobile. But wondered if Adobe Animate has any direct plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a Sprite Sheet in the Flash
There is a video on the site, it shows that Adobe Flash has a way to make it:
https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/export-animation-sprite-sheet.html